# Проблемы с кодировкой баз MySQL

Tags: mysql

Создаю я phpMyAdmin (или декстопном визуальном редакторе) базу данных, создаю в ней таблицу, но при попытке заполнения данными на кириллице выдает такую ошибку:

> `1366 - Incorrect string value: '\xD1\x8B\xD0\xB2\xD0\xB0' for column 'name' at row 1`

В файле my.cnf везде прописал utf-8, в настройках самой программы - также... Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это как раз и есть UTF-8 в битовом представлении.
Тебе нужен windows-1251.
Ну или что-нибудь другое.